# Using @JsonTypeInfo why can't the polymorphic field be omitted?

Tags: java, jackson

Here is a polymorphic field:

```
@JsonProperty("config")
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "keystone", value = KeystoneConfig.class),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "internal", value = InternalConfig.class)
})
@Nullable
abstract Configuration getConfig();
```

where `Configuration` is an interface, and `type` is a `String` field elsewhere in the structure/class.

This works fine with a response payload (something) like this:

```
{ "type": "internal",
  "config": { "int1": "value1" }
}
```

but fails with a deserialization parsing error when the `config` field is omitted, like this:

```
{ "type": "internal"
}
```

Normally, when fields are omitted, we get the Java default value (I expected `null` in this case).  I wish to retain the discriminator field `type`, but allow the `config` field to be optional.

How can I get that behaviour in this case?

Comment: Had the same issue, fixed it by returning a new Object (of type other than the mentioned ones here) when it should be null. For example, @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "noConfig", value = NullConfig.class)

Answer (score 1):

`JacksonAnnotationIntrospector`, `JsonDeserializer` and `JsonTypeResolver` seems do not help for your case. 
At the time being, I can only come up a work around by deserializing the json string with 3 step as follows:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
// 1. deserializing the json string into JsonNode
JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(json);
// 2. Add a empty node if "config" property is not found
JsonNode configNode = jsonNode.get("config");
if (jsonNode.isObject() && (configNode == null || configNode.size() == 0)) {
    ((ObjectNode) jsonNode).put("config", "");
}
// 3. Convert to desired class
mapper.treeToValue(jsonNode, Foo.class);
```